# Flutter, text alignment issue

Tags: flutter, dart

What am I doing: I want to show button text and one more button one under the other.

Problem: When I click the button, the text and the other button at the bottom change places.

How can I fix this problem?

```
 return Scaffold(
      body: Consumer2<ThemeNotifier, RecorderNotifier>(
        builder: (context, theme, recorder, child) => Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 32.0),
            Center(
              child: Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                children: [
                  Visibility(
                    visible: recorder.isRecording,
                    child: Lottie.asset('assets/recording_animation.json'),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: mRed,
                      border: recorder.isRecording ? null : Border.all(),
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    ),
                    child: IconButton(
                      color: mWhiteColor,
                      iconSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3,
                      icon: Icon(
                        recorder.isRecording
                            ? Icons.stop_rounded
                            : Icons.keyboard_voice_outlined,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () => recorder.isRecording
                          ? RecorderService().stopRecord(recorder)
                          : RecorderService().startRecord(recorder),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 32.0),
            const Text(
              'Example',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32.0),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 32.0),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a Stack, the widgets are placed on top of each other in the order they're created. In your case, there's a Container with an IconButton on top of a Lottie animation.

When you hide the Lottie animation, it changes the order of the widgets in the Stack, which can move the IconButton to a different spot. To fix this, you can use the Positioned tool to place the Container and Lottie animation based on the top and bottom of the screen.

```dart
    //**Here's an example of how you can update your code to use Positioned:**   
       /// code...
        return Scaffold(
              body: Consumer2<ThemeNotifier, RecorderNotifier>(
                builder: (context, theme, recorder, child) => Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(height: 32.0),
                    Visibility(
                      visible: recorder.isRecording,
                      child: Lottie.asset('assets/recording_animation.json'),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                    Positioned(
                      bottom: 0.0,
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: mRed,
                          border: recorder.isRecording ? null : Border.all(),
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        ),
                        child: IconButton(
                          color: mWhiteColor,
                          iconSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3,
                          icon: Icon(
                            recorder.isRecording
                                ? Icons.stop_rounded
                                : Icons.keyboard_voice_outlined,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () => recorder.isRecording
                              ? RecorderService().stopRecord(recorder)
                              : RecorderService().startRecord(recorder),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
```

Comment: Yes I got the error, it got resolved when I wrapped it with Sizedbox instead of Positioned. Thanks.